# WP touch widgets

Tags: php, html, ios, wordpress

Hi guys I'm using wp touch to develop a mobile wordpress site, but when I try to do something like `dynamic_sidebar('sidebar')` it return `false` in the main theme I can use widgets, but I want them to be also available in wp touch any idea if It can be done?

Comment: Return Value of dynamic_sidebar : `True, if widget sidebar was found and called. False if not found or not called. ` Can you share your main theme's and mobile theme's sidebar.php files?

Comment: Here you go http://pastebin.com/r8uTtCqT the funny thing is that get_meta returns the correct id....I guess my only way to do it is to query the database but I don't know how to get the content for a widget only with `dinamyc_sidebar`

Comment: And I tested it, the main theme returns the same id for `sidebar_id`

Comment: In your main theme you are using : `$pageid = $wp_query->post->ID;` and in your mobile theme : `get_the_ID()` are you sure these are returning same ID ?

Comment: Yes same ID, I tested it now again.I guess the mai solution it will be to query the database? do you know how to do it?

Comment: If you want to do queries, you can use  $wpdb . http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb . But i'm not sure, what you will query exactly ?

Comment: Mmmm yeah that's true, the main problem is dynamic_sidebar, is there another alternative for displaying widgets content?

Comment: can you share your all `register_sidebar()` functions from your functions.php file ?

Comment: Omg I'm so retarded I was editing the wrong file :)))) geeez

Comment: OK, now please accept my question : "**Edit right file**" . haha :)

Comment: Mmmm looks like still doesn't work....ah!!!

Comment: can you share your all `register_sidebar()` functions from your functions.php file ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LAMduBjq This is in my main theme not the mobile one, in the mobile one I don't have anything, ah btw as you know the wp touch theme is located in plugins folder, not in the main themes folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOrdpress couldn't find `sidebar` sidebar on your mobile theme because it's not defined in your mobile themes `functions.php` (in `wp-content/plugins/wptouch/themes/THEMENAME/)`.

So you have to add this :

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
        register_sidebar(array(
                'name' => 'Sidebar',
                'id' => 'sidebar',
                'before_widget' => '<div class="sidepanel">',
                'after_widget' => '</div>',
                'before_title' => '<h3>',
                'after_title' => '</h3>'
        ));
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, returns false `<?php var_dump(dynamic_sidebar($sidebar_id)); ?>` :( I will die with this problem I guess

Comment: Ok I've solved it, I copied all the content from functions.php(main theme) and copied to the mobile one, and it works, post this as an answer so I can accept it, at least that's what I can do here in order to thank you for your time. :D